# c++, storing keys and values inside of a map by using for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, dictionary

hey guys I'm trying to modify my code and got curious if that can work.

right now I have two for loops that read from two files
and store values into two arrays
kinda like this:

```
fstream infile(file_name.c_str());

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        infile >> array[i];
}

infile.close();
```

is there a way to modify it by substituting two arrays with a map?
kinda like this:

```
fstream infile1(file_name1.c_str());
fstream infile2(file_name2.c_str());

map<string,float>my_map;    

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        infile1 >>my_map<string> ;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        infile2 >>my_map<float> ;
```

Comment: Side note: if you use C++11, you don't need `.c_str()`, as now `fstream` objects accept `std::string` as constructor parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to input the data into a map you need to get the values from the file and then add them to the map.  Note that a map has unique keys so if a key repeats this will overwrite what was previously in the map.  If you do not want that then you would need to use a `std::multimap`.  If you need to use a `std::multimap` this solution will not work as it has no `[]` operator.

```
fstream infile1(file_name1.c_str());
fstream infile2(file_name2.c_str());

map<string,float>my_map;

std::string temp;
float number;

while(infile1 >> temp && infile2 >> number)
    my_map[temp] = number;
```

Also note that if your strings contain spaces then you need to replace `infile1 >> temp` with `getline(infile1, temp)`.